# nc tag: should it cover ncat, netcat, and/or socat?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created the [`nc` tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/nc/info). In the guidance section, I only talk about `nc`, but in the description part I breezily list `ncat`, `netcat`, and `socat` as similar programs.

My question is whether I should explicitly recommend using this tag for questions about all four programs, or should each program get a separate tag?

Being non-POSIX, we have four different programs that all provide the same core set of functionality, but which have different command line interfaces and different sets of unique peripheral features.

Currently, the `nc` tag is only used on 8 questions, three of which actually seem to be about `netcat`.

There is no `ncat` tag, perhaps reflecting its relative youth.

There *is* a [`socat` tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/socat/info), used on 27 questions, but without any guidance or description.

So, merge or split?

Comment: I don't have much experience with these tools. Is the syntax of the other three close enough to `nc` to merit sharing a tag? Can you be an expert in `nc` but have no idea how `netcat` works? If they can be merged, I would be inclined to make `netcat` the master tag as that is the best known one (or so I think, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Are `nc` and `netcat` even different programs? I thought that "`nc`" was the name of the "netcat" program, in the sense that "`rm`" is the name of the "remove" program and "`vi`" is the name of the "visual editor" program.

Comment: @G-Man: There are [a whole bunch of `netcat` variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations). Some are called `nc`, some `netcat`, and some install a link from one name to the other.

Comment: I’m not sure how that responds to my question. Based on my understanding of what Wikipedia says, if we’re going to consider the possibility of having separate tags for “nc” and “netcat”, then we should also have tags for “gnu-netcat”, “openbsd-netcat”, “freebsd-netcat”, “cygwin-netcat”, “macports-netcat”, “busybox-netcat”, “windows-netcat” and “wince-netcat” (or “netcat-gnu”, “netcat-openbsd”, etc.) and “cryptcat”, “pnetcat”, “sock”, “socket-(program)”, and “sbd” — … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  because “netcat” isn’t a program, *per se*; it’s a family of programs. My point is that it doesn’t make sense to say that “nc” and “netcat” are two different programs — either they’re the same program, or they’re a dozen different programs, but not two. I believe that “nc” should be an alias for “netcat”.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  To get to the point, we need somebody who knows these programs well to provide some guidance on how different they are. Note, for reference, that we have separate tags for “awk”, “gawk”, and “mawk”. Usage of the plain “awk” tag outnumbers the others by a ratio of over 35:1, even though many of the answers to “awk” questions depend on GNU features. There’s a similar situation with “grep”. And another note: ISTR that [SU] briefly had an “ncat” tag, and it went away.

Comment: @G-Man: Are you definitively saying that a command line format defines the scope of a tag? Two different command line schema equals two different tags? If so, that answers the question.

Comment: (1) I’m not saying anything definitively. I’m just an ordinary user here; I’m just offering my opinions.  (2) I’m not sure what you mean about “command line schema”, but I tend to agree with @terdon: if it’s possible to be an expert in `nc` but have no idea how `ncat` works, they should probably be different tags — although  I guess frequency/demand is also a factor. If a tag has only eight questions, and it’s covered by another tag, then maybe it shouldn’t exist.